# How to filter array on the basis of some value contained within that

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsarray, nspredicate

I have collection of objects in array as follows.

```
arr_recipes = [{
  recipe.name = r1,
  recipe_tags = [t1, t2, t3]
},
{
 recipe.name = r1,
 recipe_tags = [t1, t2]
},
{
 recipe.name = r1,
 recipe_tags = [t4, t5, t6]
}]
```

Now, i want to search the content of arr_recipes by tag name i.e. if I type t1, it should return result below:

```
 arr_searchresult= [{
  recipe.name = r1,
  recipe_tags = [t1, t2, t3]
},
{
 recipe.name = r1,
 recipe_tags = [t1, t2, t3]
}
}]
```

If i type, t3 in uisearhcbar, i should get result as below :

```
arr_searchresult = [{
  recipe.name = r1,
  recipe_tags = [t1, t2, t3]
}]
```

Can anyone suggest me the predicate to obtian tha above serch result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
NSArray *arr_recipes = @[@{@"recipe.name" : @"r1",
                         @"recipe_tags" : @[@"t1", @"t2", @"t3"]},
                         @{@"recipe.name" : @"r1",
                         @"recipe_tags" : @[@"t1", @"t2"] } ];

NSString *searchText = @"t3"; // set your search field value.

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe_tags contains[cd] %@", searchText];

NSArray *filteredArray = [arr_recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```